# Can the power operator ** be used with arbitrarily large operands?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can the power operator `**` be used with arbitrarily large operands?

For example:

```
   reg [100:0] c;  
   reg [15:0] a;  
   reg [15:0] b;  
   c = a**b;
```

Is there is some maximum limit on operand size?

Comment: Power operator '**' is supported only for the results that do not exceed the
size of 'real' data type. The size of the real operator is 8 byte, this is the most common limit followed by eda vendors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) doesn't mention any maximum size of operands.

But... different IDE might have some limitations in `**` operator usage, e.g. it works only in case like `2**n` or length of the operands is limited. However, there should be no limitations in simulations (e.g. Riviera-PRO allowed to simulate `a**b` operation, with a and b length equal to 150, without any warning).

When using power operator for synthesis, it's sythesizable as long as `a=2`. In that case the power operator simply "change" to shifter.

Comment: I don't think `**` is synthesizable anyway.

Comment: @Qiu, thanks. For pure testbench simulation, do you think there should be some limitation on ** operator?

Comment: @quartz: I don't know about all IDE, but I was able to simulate `a**b` in Riviera-PRO, with `a` and `b` length equal 151.

Comment: @EugeneSh. According to Sec. 7.3.1.5 of IEEE Std. 1364.1-2002(E) the `**` operator is synthesizable as long as both operands are constant or the first operand is 2.